# My XML preview plane is not showing . How to get it back?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried the preview plane option . I have even tried to restore the default . Recently installed Android Studio . Please help if anyone

Comment: view > Tool Windows > Preview

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps you can get preview plane :- 
View -> Tool windows -> preview